# Cross compiling for windows. Objcopy appears to be giving bad object file

Tags: c++, linux, windows, cross-compiling, objcopy

I have a program I originally wrote in linux which uses objcopy to embed some images within the executable to be used at runtime. I have no problems with this in linux at all and it runs fine.

However when I try and cross compile the program for windows, I get a list of undefined references at the linking stage, suggesting to me objcopy is failing. Could someone please point me in the right direction to get this to cross compile correctly. I know this is not a code problem as the code is portable.

Command used to cross compile with objcopy

```
i586-mingw32msvc-objcopy --input binary --output=pe-i386 --binary-architecture i386 images/HD44780.bmp HD44780_bmp.o
```

Resulting error at linking stage

```
HDxx780.o:HDxx780.cpp:(.text+0xbe2): undefined reference to `__binary_images_HD44780_bmp_end'
HDxx780.o:HDxx780.cpp:(.text+0xbef): undefined reference to `__binary_images_HD44780_bmp_start'
HDxx780.o:HDxx780.cpp:(.text+0xc04): undefined reference to `__binary_images_HD44780_bmp_start'
```

The macros I have in my code to access the data

```
extern char _binary_images_HD44780_bmp_start, _binary_images_HD44780_bmp_end;

#define HD44780_DATA ((void *) &_binary_images_HD44780_bmp_start)
#define HD44780_SIZE ((size_t) (&_binary_images_HD44780_bmp_end - &_binary_images_HD44780_bmp_start))
```

Supported formats by i586-mingw32-objcopy

```
me@mypc:~/ > i586-mingw32msvc-objcopy --info
BFD header file version (GNU Binutils) 2.20
pe-i386
(header little endian, data little endian)
  i386
pei-i386
(header little endian, data little endian)
  i386
elf32-i386
(header little endian, data little endian)
  i386
elf32-little
(header little endian, data little endian)
  i386
elf32-big
(header big endian, data big endian)
  i386
srec
(header endianness unknown, data endianness unknown)
  i386
symbolsrec
(header endianness unknown, data endianness unknown)
  i386
verilog
(header endianness unknown, data endianness unknown)
  i386
tekhex
(header endianness unknown, data endianness unknown)
  i386
binary
(header endianness unknown, data endianness unknown)
  i386
ihex
(header endianness unknown, data endianness unknown)
  i386

      pe-i386 pei-i386 elf32-i386 elf32-little elf32-big srec 
      i386 pe-i386 pei-i386 elf32-i386 elf32-little elf32-big srec 

      symbolsrec verilog tekhex binary ihex 
      i386 symbolsrec verilog tekhex binary ihex
```

Im trying to compile to Windows (x86).
The machine im compiling with is Linux (x86).

Comment: You might have the wrong format selected, what formats are listed by `i586-mingw32msvc-objcopy -i` ?

Comment: I did wonder if this was the case but wasn't sure what the correct format would be. Ive updated the question to include the info about objcopy.

Comment: I think the formats used on Windows are `coff-i386` (used by Microsoft tools) and `elf32-i386` (used by gcc).  You can probably look at one of the `.o` files created by your compiler to know for sure, the `file` command usually will tell you the format.

Comment: Is there any tool to check the symbols in HD44780_bmp.o after objcopy?

Comment: @JackyZhu: Yes, `i586-mingw32msvc-nm` should do it.  Or if it's in Microsoft format, `objdump` that comes with the Windows SDK.

Comment: running file on one of the ok .o files returns "80386 COFF executable not stripped - version 30821". but if i try passing coff-i386 to objcopy is returns "Invalid bfd target". i586-mingw32msvc-nm did let me check the symbols and there are correct.

Comment: The symbol names in your object files are probably being mangled slightly differently.  As Ben Voigt suggested, use the `i586-mingw32msvc-nm` tool to check the symbol names being stored in the object file -- the symbols are probably there, but they likely have slightly different names than you're expecting.

Comment: @Adam I did check with that tool and they are correct. Output as follows:`i586-mingw32msvc-nm HD44780_bmp.o
00069036 D _binary_images_HD44780_bmp_end
00069036 A _binary_images_HD44780_bmp_size
00000000 D _binary_images_HD44780_bmp_start`

these symbol names match what is in my macros

Comment: Ok, can you run `file` on both a good `.o` and the bad one created by `objcopy` and compare?

Comment: Also, the output of `i586-mingw32msvc-nm` should have as many leading underscores as the link errors, and one more than what the source code uses.  But it has the same number as the source code.  Try removing the leading underscore from the source code.

Comment: @BenVolgt Just tried removing the leading underscore in the source code, and it worked. So how come when I compile natively in linux, I need the leading underscore. But when i cross compile to windows, I don't?